# Send messages between 2 Ubuntu PCs (Net Send Style)

Tags: networking, notification

I am trying to find a way to send a message (like a popup message) from 1 PC to another. both are using Ubuntu. Already tried the smbclient way but this only works between a linux PC to a windows PC. I need a way to send messages from an Ubuntu PC to another Ubuntu PC. Similar to the way of Windows Net Send.

Comment: notify-send sends a pop up on my terminal but I wanted to send a popup to other users (may be a list of specific users) but without using sudo or ssh , do I have any alternative .A command which works as "notify-send" but to send message on other user terminal.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Install `ssh` and `libnotify-bin` (via terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install ssh libnotify-bin
```

on both computers.

(You may have `libnotify-bin` installed already. Mine had it already.)

Then SSH (via the terminal) into the other computer:

```
ssh <user name>@<ip address>
```

And then when you're logged in, type:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
notify-send "Title of message" "message text"
```

Happy message-sending!
(or scaring XD)

Comment: Even though this is a very intelligent answer am trying to find a way to send it without ssh. With the ssh option i already know it works (using wall for example) but your notify-send is very smart.

Comment: After searching several methods this one is the best. Because of 2 reasons: 1. ssh gives me some security over doing this and 2. The use of DISPLAY allows to select to which video the message will show. I tested using ssh user@ip/domain 'DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "TITLE" "MESSAGE"'

Comment: It may work in a home enviorment, but in a large organisation, i am not sure if it is possible to install SSH on every client system, I have experience as in my office there are about 100 coms, there should be another way to send a message with out installing SSh

Comment: Check out my answer for accomplishing this without ssh! :)

Answer (score 33):

I read you wanted to do this without SSH, I believe I have a solution: `netcat` [nc]
It comes with Ubuntu by default.

First we need a "daemon" to run in the background. Second, we need a program to make the alert pop up.  I have `zenity` installed.  If you do not, please install it, or edit the script to use whatever you like [e.x. `xmessage`, but that is ugly]. Next, paste this into 'daemon.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash
port=3333
nc -l $port | while read msg; do zenity --info --text "$msg"; done
```

Now, make it executable `chmod +x daemon.sh`, now run it in the background: `./daemon.sh &`

Now you're done!  Well, you actually need to do this on *each* computer.  You also will want to automate the start of the daemon.  Open the 'startup' applications from the menu, and add your script.  Once that's done, to send a message to the other computer, type in:

`nc 192.168.1.X 3333` then type your message and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Each enter line will make a message pop up. To exit nc, press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>C</kbd>, or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>D</kbd>.

Just make sure to replace 192.168.1.X with the real local IP of the other PC. [You can use `ifconfig` to find the IP address]

You could also make another script, say, `message.sh`.  In that, paste:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc 192.168.2.X 3333
```

Then `chmod +x message.sh`.  Then you can just type `./message.sh` then type your message, then enter, and your message is sent.  Also, now that I think of it, you could also add a sound notification.  I would recommend `mplayer`, it's a CLI media player. Shouldn't be too hard to figure out, but if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: This is a neat solution, but I kinda prefer SSH because of security purposes.

Comment: Someone told me you can use `socat` instead of netcat, for SSL encryption.  I never looked into it though.

Comment: Wow! nicely done! I changed it a bit to work with notify-osd: `nc -l $port | while read msg; do notify-send "$HOSTNAME" "$msg" -i gtk-network; done`

Comment: Or with remote-connector ip address: `while true; do nc -l -v 3333 2> status | while read msg; do ip=$(cat status | grep -o -P '(?<=from).*(?=port)') && notify-send "$ip" "$msg" -i gtk-network; done ; done`

Comment: You can use `cryptcat` to make your communication encrypted with a password. It works as same as `nc`

Answer (score 17):

Use [`nc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to send text between two computers on the same network (without encryption).

On the **receiving** computer do

```
nc -l 3333
```

On the **sending** computer do

```
nc 192.168.1.XX 3333
```

then just start typing and the text will show up on the other computer (after you press enter) until you hit ctlr+c.

---

You can [get the IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565139/3064538) of the receiving computer with `hostname -I` (run that on the receiving computer).

You don't have to use port 3333, use any number between [1025](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363892/what-non-standard-ports-are-safe-to-use) and [65535](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113224/what-is-the-largest-tcp-ip-network-port-number-allowable-for-ipv4) inclusive.

Remember that this is **not encrypted**. Any computer on your network can see what text you're transferring.

Comment: Neat!  When I do `hostname -I` I got 2 IP addresses, only the second one works.