# Network notify-send over two Ubu machines

Tags: networking, notify-send

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send messages between 2 Ubuntu PCs (Net Send Style)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31582/send-messages-between-2-ubuntu-pcs-net-send-style)

I'm looking for a way of using something like `notify-send` over my local network. I know I can use Netstat for network chat but is there someway to use the DBus type messages that Gnome pops up over a network?

I have 3 computers running at all times in my network working on things, I would like for my scripts to be able to notify me when done on my main work PC.

**EDIT:** Ok the link below is fine, and the script was working that the user posted:

```
#!/bin/bash
port=3333
nc -l $port | while read msg; do notify-send Alert "$msg"; done
```

But for some reason it won't stay open, it runs for the first message then turns off the script. I need the script to stay open all the time until I close it. What can I do to fix this?